# Creating vertical divider with CSS3 / Compass rather than using image

Tags: image, css, compass-sass, mixins, divider

Here's a screenshot of my existing image-based vertical divider for menu items (hopefully you can see it):

[image]

(1) What's the best way to replace this image with a custom CSS3 style? Dimensions are 3x27.

(2) Does Compass offer a mixin for vertical dividers? That would be preferable, and if so, no need to address (1).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if compass has something for this but couldn't you use regular css borders. border-right:1px solid white then on the last one say dont have a border.